# Saving percentiles from centile command

Tags: stata, percentile

I am using the command `centile` in Stata. And I want to store the result in a local matrix or vector.

I know I can get the result of a single centile using `r(c_#)`. But I am calculating 50 centiles, and want to store all of them in one local vector/matrix without having to write all of them out.

**Update:**
I have found the following solution, but I would still appreciate a more  elegant answer.

```
centile var, centile(0(5)100)
forval i=1/21{
    local cut_`i'= r(c_`i')
}
display `cut_1' `cut_2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some small technique. Note that a matrix or vector isn't considered "local", although its name could be held in a local macro.

```
sysuse auto, clear
centile mpg, centile(0(5)100)
matrix results = J(21,1, .)

forval i = 1/21 {
    matrix results[`i', 1] = r(c_`i')
}
```